# Custom JsonConverter is ignored for DEserialization when using custom contract resolver instead of JsonConverter attribute

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

I am using Json.NET (6.0.3) for serialization. I wrote a custom JsonConverter `TestConverter` that handles instances of some `BaseClass` (by converting them to an integer id and back). Everything is working fine when I annotate the properties in my classes with `JsonConverter[typeof(TestConverter)]`.

I would however very much prefer to use a custom contract resolver instead, which should, according to the [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ContractResolver.htm), be able to fully replace all attribute usage.

Here's how I set up the contract resolver:

```
protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
    var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
    if (typeof(BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
    {
        property.Converter = new TestConverter();
    }
    return property;
}
```

Everything is working fine for serialization, however it seems that the converter I set up in the contract resolver are *completely ignored* during the deserialization process. The `ReadJson`method of `TestConverter` is never called.

Am I missing something really obvious? Do I need to attach the converter to property in some other place?

I created a small runable example that demonstrates the problem. If the `[JsonConverter]` attribute in line 57 is commented out, the program will crash with an exception because Json.net is trying to convert an integer to an object instead of using the `TestConverter`.
The source for the example can be found here: http://pastebin.com/xgVS6hXY

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `[JsonConverter(typeof(TestConverter))]` attribute from the Artist property of `Song` class. Change the setup of the contract resolver to the following sample:

```
public class TestContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (typeof(BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
        {
            var converter = new TestConverter();
            property.Converter = converter;
            property.MemberConverter  = converter;
        }
        return property;
    }
}
```

Everything should work fine.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Do you happen to know what the difference between the two is / why I need two settings? I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330008/the-difference-between-converter-and-memberconverter-properties-of-json-nets-js) SO question, but it doesn't really help.