# Creating a predefined JsonConvert attribute?

Tags: c#, properties, json.net, converters, customization

My problem is quite simple..
What I would like to do is this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter)]
object SomeProperty {get;set;}
```

But be able to write it as a custom attribute so I simply can decorate my properties with a pre-defined JsonConverter attribute.. so for instance

```
[MyCustomConverter]
object SomeProperty {get;set;}
```

Would in this case be treated as `[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]`

Any ideas?

Br,
Inx

Answer (score 1):

It's not trivial, but you can do this if you implement a custom `IContractResolver` that takes your attributes into account.

There are several steps involved in doing this:

1. Create an `abstract` base class for your attributes that extends `System.Attribute`:

   ```
   public abstract class ConverterAttribute : Attribute
   {
       public abstract JsonConverter Converter { get; }
   }
   ```
2. Next, you need to create the `IContractResolver` that will actually use your attribute<sup>1</sup>:

   ```
   public class CustomAttributeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
   {   
       protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
       {
           JsonObjectContract contract =
               base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);

           IEnumerable<JsonProperty> withoutConverter =
               contract.Properties.Where(
                   pr => pr.MemberConverter == null && 
                   pr.Converter == null);

           // Go over the results of calling the default implementation.
           // check properties without converters for your custom attribute
           // and pull the custom converter out of that attribute.
           foreach (JsonProperty property in withoutConverter)
           {
               PropertyInfo info = 
                   objectType.GetProperty(property.UnderlyingName);

               var converterAttribute =
                   info.GetCustomAttribute<ConverterAttribute>();

               if (converterAttribute != null)
               {
                   property.Converter = converterAttribute.Converter;
                   property.MemberConverter = converterAttribute.Converter;
               }
           }

           return contract;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create the attribute that overrrides `ConverterAttribute.Converter`, returning your custom converter:

   ```
   public class MyCustomConverterAttribute : ConverterAttribute
   {
       get { return new MyCustomConverter(); }
   }
   ```
4. Decorate your class with the attribute:

   ```
   public class MyClass
   {
       [MyCustomConverter]
       public object MyProperty { get; set; }
   }
   ```
5. When serializing or deserializing, specify the contract resolver in the `JsonSerializerSettings` you use:

   ```
   var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
   settings.ContractResolver = new CustomAttributeContractResolver();

   string serialized = JsonConverter.SerializeObject(new MyClass());
   ```

I'd say that this probably isn't worth the small benefit--all you're really doing is saving a few characters, unless your attribute does something else.

---

<sup>1</sup>: I'm not sure what the difference between `MemberConverter` and `Converter`. When *serializing*, only the `Converter` property was needed, but deserializing required `MemberConverter`. I'll keep digging, but hopefully someone can provide some insight. Looks like [others have had this same question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18330008/497356).

Comment: Hi!
It seams like even if i decorate my property with [MyCustomConverter].. the withoutConverter-object within the CustomAttributeContractResolver still picks up the decorated property..

Comment: Its supposed to -- `withoutConverter` holds properties without a `JsonConverter` attribute. It should pick up the property and then use the attribute's underlying `Converter`.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear to be possible. The `JsonConverterAttribute` and `TypeConverterAttribute` classes are both sealed, and these are the classes used by Json.NET to supply a custom type converter.